# Combine multiple API in one laravel

Tags: php, api, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have started learning laravel this month, working on API, just controller and models.

I have some API like searching by Name, Type, Area, Rating, Reviews
each responds to these urls

localhost:8000/api/vendors/name/test

localhost:8000/api/vendors/type/student

localhost:8000/api/vendors/area/asia

I am facing a big problem here, I have around 10 field which can be searched individually, but problem is they can be search in one query, like Name and Type, Name and Area, Name Type and Area, Name Type Area and Reviews. There will be many combinations.

I have made a different method in controller for now. But I feel this way would be difficult for me to make a different method for each query.

My Question is, Is there any way to merge these queries simply, like have a method which calls different methods relatively. 
like Name Type and Area, method calls Name first, it get some result, now on the result Type method is called, on it's result Area method is called.

right now my api.php look like this

```
Route::get('/vendors/name/{name}','VendorsController@ByName');
Route::get('/vendors/type/{type}','VendorsController@ByType');
Route::get('/vendors/area/{area}','VendorsController@ByArea');
Route::get('/vendors/rating/{rating}','VendorsController@ByRating');
Route::get('/vendors/reviews/{reviews}','VendorsController@ByReviews');

Route::get('/vendors/name/{name}/type/{type}','VendorsController@ByNameType');
Route::get('/vendors/name/{name}/area/{area}','VendorsController@ByNameArea');
Route::get('/vendors/type/{type}/area/{area}','VendorsController@ByTypeArea');

Route::get('/vendors/name/{name}/type/{type}/area/{area}','VendorsController@ByNameTypeArea');
```

and Controller file is

```
public function ByName($Name)
{
    $Vendors = Vendors::where('Name', 'like', '%'.$Name.'%')
    ->with('venues')->paginate(30);
    return $Vendors;
}

public function ByType($Type)
{
    $Types = explode('-', $Type);

    $Vendors = Vendors::whereIn('Type', $Types)
    ->with('venues')->paginate(30);
    return $Vendors;
}

public function ByArea($Area)
{
    $Vendors = Vendors::where('Area', 'like', '%'.$Area.'%')
    ->with('venues')->paginate(30);
    return $Vendors;
}

public function ByRating($Rating)
{
    $Ratings = explode('-', $Rating);

    $Vendors = Vendors::whereBetween('Rating', $Ratings)
    ->with('venues')->paginate(30);
    return $Vendors;
}

public function ByReviews($Review)
{
    $Reviews = explode('-', $Review);

    $Vendors = Vendors::whereBetween('Reviews', $Reviews)
    ->with('venues')->paginate(30);
    return $Vendors;
}

public function ByNameType($Name, $Type)
{
    $Types = explode('-', $Type);

    $Vendors = Vendors::where('Name', 'like', '%'.$Name.'%')
    ->whereIn('Type', $Types)
    ->with('venues')->paginate(30);
    return $Vendors;
}

public function ByNameArea($Name, $Area)
{
    $Vendors = Vendors::where('Name', 'like', '%'.$Name.'%')
    ->where('Area', 'like', '%'.$Area.'%')
    ->with('venues')->paginate(30);
    return $Vendors;
}

public function ByTypeArea($Type, $Area)
{
    $Types = explode('-', $Type);

    $Vendors = Vendors::where('Area', 'like', '%'.$Area.'%')
    ->whereIn('Type', $Types)
    ->with('venues')->paginate(30);
    return $Vendors;
}

public function ByNameTypeArea($Name, $Type, $Area)
{
    $Types = explode('-', $Type);

    $Vendors = Vendors::where('Name', 'like', '%'.$Name.'%')
    ->where('Area', 'like', '%'.$Area.'%')
    ->whereIn('Type', $Types)
    ->with('venues')->paginate(30);
    return $Vendors;
}
```

Comment: One suggestion is to add slug for all, declare an array for possible values, then check if the slug is in array, if so, then proceed writing the query for that. This minimizes the number of functions used

Comment: I have got another idea, to try searching with GET parameters, will add multiple checks. This will be done in 1 method?